# security protocol used by Microsoft Graph api

Tags: ssl, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to find out the security protocols supported by Microsoft Graph API and the Office 365 Management APIs.
I could see Office365 supports TLS1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS1.2, but they are going to stop support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1, sooner.
Does the above statement holds true for the aforementioned APIs as well? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has teams dedicated to infrastructure and security making those decisions (which security protocols to support and which ones to drop).
Even if the roll out of those changes might not be identical from one service to another, eventually those things align.

So yes, in the long run, Microsoft graph will most likely drop support for TLS 1.0 and 1.0. Especially since change notifications has dropped it support for outbound calls. I can't provide any time frame though.

Comment: TLS is designed on such a way that the highest version supported by both parties will be used. And as you can see here, the highest supported version by Microsoft graph at the moment is 1.2. https://www.ssllabs.com/analyze.html?d=graph.microsoft.com&s=20.190.132.118&latest